# How do I call an external stylesheet from a .cshtml page?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view page (View.cshtml) and a stylesheet (Style.css).

The stylesheet is located in a folder called "Stylesheet", and the view page is located in Views/Home/View.cshtml. I am trying to link the stylesheet to the view page by this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Stylesheet/Style.css">
```

When I run the project, it showed the contents of the view page but the styling was not implemented. May I know what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

**View.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Stylesheet/Style.css" /> ‌
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="topHeader">
        <br />

        <div id="credentialsBox">

            <div id="texts">
                <div id="word1">Username:</div>
                <div id="word2">Password:</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Style.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'proximanova';
    src: url('../fonts/proximanova-light-webfont (2)_0.ttf') format('truetype');
}


/*CSS Styling Properties*/
body {
    font-family: proximanova;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #007381;
}

#topHeader{
    margin-top: 15%;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
}

#credentialsBox {
    border-radius: 3%;
    width: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -5%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#texts {
    padding: 14%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        @RenderSection("css", false)
    </head>

    <body>
        @RenderBody()
    </body>

</html>
```

Sorry if the CSS styling is a bit messy, I am trying my best to learn here :D

Comment: You can try this:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{http/https}://{url/ipaddress}/{dir}/{stylesheet}.css">

Comment: Your code looks fine. Have you used your browser tools to check if its being loaded?

Comment: Why styling is not implemented ? , can you show more of your view and some basic style you applied to help others guide better.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am getting errors with Style.css when I checked with the browser tools. On the network tab, it says my css is (blocked:other). Under the Console tab, it said not allowed to load local resource

Comment: @stom I have updated the question, thanks!

Comment: That should not be happening based on the code you have shown. You should edit your question with the full details of the error message (although you could also try `href="@Url.Content("~/Stylesheet/Style.css")"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am unable to see any error via the error log, it just appear in the browser tools. I have tried the code provided, it doesn't work as well. I have been trying different methods for the past 3 hours :(

Comment: Does your server have permission to view that folder, if so is it set up to serve css files?  Also if you try to browse to the css file directly, what happens?

Comment: @Pete I am running it locally, what do you mean "Browse to the css file directly"?

Comment: Can you just paste your local host `Url` in browser like: `http://localhost:0000/Stylesheet/Style.css` and hit enter , check whether you can see your raw css file in browser ?

Comment: @stom It states "This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address:"

Comment: `The stylesheet is located in a folder called "Stylesheet"` - And where is the "StyleSheet" folder located? Do note that `@Url.Content("~/StyleSheet/Style.css")` is the root of the IIS application (which may or may not be the root of the web site depending on how it is configured in IIS/IIS Express).

Comment: my style.css is in a folder “Stylesheet” in the directory of the solution explorer

Answer (score 2):

You can also  use [@Url.Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx) instead for absolute path of `css` file.

```
<link href="~/Stylesheet/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

or

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Stylesheet/Style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I have tried but it does not work! The ones you asked me to try on the main question returned me with errors as well.

Comment: ok , there might be issue with IIS port being used or some missing settings in your project. It would be better to reproduce the issue create a new mvc project and paste all the view and css file to check again.

Answer (score 0):

If you that is your own custom CSS file then make sure that you add that file to BundleConfig.cs file in App_Start folder. Which will look something like this..

```
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/Style.css));
```

And in your head section try to replace

```
<head>
    @RenderSection("css", false)
</head>
```

with

```
  <head>
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
  </head>
```

and see it will make any difference, and we will go from there.

Comment: Hi, I do not have a BundleConfig.cs file, as I am running on ASP.NET5 WebApp

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the error. I placed my stylesheet inside "wwwroot/css" and it worked.